# Proving the existence of a linear map such that a function diagram is commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The following is a theorem that I'm trying to prove:[image: Lemma about Quotient Vector Spaces]

---

Proof Idea:

So, I'm kind of stuck on this problem. Like, I don't have a proof but I have an idea for how it could go. I'm just having a hard time figuring out the last few steps.

Proving uniqueness really isn't the issue. In fact, in proving uniqueness, I got the idea that I could just define $\phi$ to be:

$$\phi = f \circ h^{-1}$$

where $h^{-1}:V/U \to V$ is a linear map that is the inverse of $h:V \to V/U$. In order for that inverse to exist, the idea I had is that $h:V \to V/U$ has to be a bijection.

Therefore, all I really have to do is to find a bijection between those two vector spaces. This didn't seem to be that hard, because I have a linear map that is an epimorphism between the two spaces given as follows:

$$\pi: V \to V/U$$
$$v \to v+U$$

It's already linear and surjective, so all I need to do is to prove injectivity. But I'm having a hard time doing that. I know that it has to do with the fact that $U \subset Ker(f)$ but I can't seem to figure out the way to use that fact in the proof.

So, could someone give me a hint on how I could continue? If my entire approach is wrong, how do I fix it?

I'd also appreciate it if you could write the proof for this as well. I'll look at your hint first and then try to construct my own proof. If I succeed in doing that, I'll have a look at your proof as a reference. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

[image: Definition of a Quotient Vector Space]

Comment: The correct way to define $\varphi$ is $\varphi([v]) = f(v)$ for $v \in V$. You can check that everything works out then. Ping me if you need more help.

Comment: @Riquelme Ummm what's [v]?

Comment: The equivalence class of $v$ in $V/U$ is usually denoted by $[v]$; it is just $[v] = v +U$.

Comment: Uh I don't know what an equivalence class is? Like, the lemma above is from the chapter on Linear Maps by Klaus Janich. I'm probably supposed to just used the material in there, and anything prior to that, to prove the lemma.

Comment: You need to know what a Quotient Space is before you can prove the lemma. I am sure Janich defined $V/U$ before he stated the lemma?

Comment: Yeap but not in terms of equivalence classes. Let me update the post with the exact definition of the quotient vector space.

Comment: So yea, I've updated the post with the definition given by Klaus Janich. No equivalence classes mentioned or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vectorspace, $U$ a linear subspace of $V$. I will use your notation: We define $\varphi \colon V/U \rightarrow V$ via $\varphi(v+U) = f(v)$ for all $v \in V$. Then it is clear that $f \circ \pi = \varphi$. You now need to check that this is well-defined, that is, if $v +U = w + u$ then $f(u) = f(w)$. If $v+U = w +U$ , then $v -w \in U \subseteq \ker(f) \Rightarrow f(v) = f(v) - f(w) + f(w) = f(v-w) +f(w) = f(w)$ by linearity of $f$ and as $v-w \in \ker(f)$. I leave it to you to check that $\varphi$ is linear.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I will try that out. Doesn't the fact that it is well-defined follow from the fact that $f:V \to W$ is well-defined (by virtue of the fact that it is a map)?

Comment: No, you really have to check that!

Comment: Okay yea that definitely worked. Thank you so much. I'm just weirded out by the fact that my idea for what $\phi$ was didn't work out. I thought i had it but i guess my intuition for this just isn't quite there yet.

Comment: You are welcome and do not worry, you will master this in not time!